# Outlook not showing recent emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

outlook is not showing recent emails . It is only showing email from February .  But i search using subject , i can find the emails .How to solve this  ? i see this document https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1709-outlook-remove-filter-applied.html  .

> In Outlook 2007, please click the View > Current View > Customize
>   Current View.
>    click the Filter button.->
>   click the Clear All button

I tried many other solutions also , But it is not working 
Please help .

Comment: In View Settings, click on Reset Current View. This takes it back to default settings. That may work for you.

Comment: Really thank you friend . But it is not working .